# How to animate CATransform3D with multiple transforms?

Tags: ios, core-animation, core-graphics, uiviewanimation

Basically, I'm rotating a layer about a point as :

```
CATransform3D transform = CATransform3DIdentity;
transform.m34 = 1.0 / -500;
transform = CATransform3DTranslate(transform, rotationPoint.x-center.x, rotationPoint.y-center.y, 0.0);
transform = CATransform3DRotate(transform, (rotationAngleFor) * M_PI / 180.0f, 0.0, 1.0, 0);
transform = CATransform3DTranslate(transform, center.x-rotationPoint.x, center.y-rotationPoint.y, 0.0);
```

I also create a layer, add it to a bigger layer and then apply the transform to it:

```
[self.layer addSublayer:myLayer];
myLayer.transform = transform;
```

How to animate this?

**Note-** Putting this in a `UIView` animation block doesn't work.

Comment: UIView animations are only meant to animate _view_ properties.

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist Exactly!

Comment: But the CATransform3D on the layer is a _layer_ property. The transform on the view is set directly on the view and is a CGAffineTransform. Please refer to [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html) for the 7 view properties that you can animate (frame, bounds, center, transform, alpha, backgroundColor, contentStretch). Transform is there but it is the _view_ transform property.

Comment: I had put that note to prevent answers suggesting `UIView` animations :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Edit:** As @DuncanC pointed out my description did not match the actual code.

You can use a `CABasicAnimation` that is added to the layer as follows.

```
CABasicAnimation *transformAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath: @"transform"];

    <here goes your definition of transform>

transformAnimation.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:newTransform];
transformAnimation.duration = 10;
[self.layer addAnimation:transformAnimation forKey:@"transform"];
```

This animation performs a continuous change of the `transform` property of the layer from the original value of the `transform` property of the layer to the `newTransform` transformation. The change takes 10 seconds.

Comment: If I don't remember wrong, the animation will happen linearly between the begin and end state (move on a straight line instead of looking like a rotation at a fixed radius). I also believe that you should set a `CAValueFunction` to make it look like it is supposed to. If I remember correctly you want to use a `kCAValueFunctionRotateY` value function.

Comment: @david, translate, rotate, translate back has the effect of creating a rotation around a point that's not the origin. If you create a transform like that and apply it to a layer, it will indeed animate that rotation of the object around some arbitrary point. It's also possible to submit a CABasicAnimation that rotates around one the axes, by using the key "transform.rotation.z" or ".y" or ".x" (depending on which axis you want to rotate around.  The animation uses ease in, ease out timing by default, so the OP will need to add code to change the timing to linear if that's what he/she wants.

Comment: @Jan, that animation will animate from the previous tranform value to the specified transform. If the previous transform value was identity, it will start from identity. If the previous layer transform was something other than the identity transform, though, then the code above will animate from that starting transform to the specified end transform.

Comment: this answer fixed my problem when trying animating multiple transforms. Thank you